# Rendering Inherit Forms adds extra labels in symfony2

Tags: forms, symfony, twig, symfony-2.6

I've achieved form's data inheritance in symfony2 following [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/inherit_data_option.html), but my problem is when I render it using `form_widget()` (Twig's function) I'm getting an extra label with the name of the inherit field.

Parent Form code:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options){
    $builder->add('username')
        ->add('email', new EmailType()) // <-- Getting child
        ->add('birthdate', 'date')
        ->add('plainPassword', new PasswordType());
}
```

Child Form code:

```
class EmailType extends AbstractType {

   public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options){
       $builder->add('email', 'email');
   }

   public function getName() {
       return 'user_email';
   }
```

}

Controller Code(Simplified):

```
 $user = new User();
 $form = $this->createForm(new RegisterType(), $user);
 return $this->render(':users:register.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView()));
```

And my rendered form looks like this:

```
<label class="required">Email</label>   
<div id="user_register_email">
    <label for="user_register_email_email" class="required">Email</label>   <--- Child's label Not wanted
    <input type="email" id="user_register_email_email" name="user_register[email][email]" required="required">
</div>
```

Anyone know why is this happening and how can it be fixed ?

I really appreciate your support :)

Comment: Do you render just using `{{ form(form) }}` or do you render each row separately like `{{ form_row(form.email) }}`? If separately, just render each internal field rather than the outer like `{{ form_row(form.email.email) }}`.

Comment: I'm using form_widget(form)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to explicitly set `label` to `false`  to prevent it from rendering.

```
$builder->add('email', new EmailType(), array(
   'label' => false,
));
```

Comment: that's it, really ?
I can't give it a tray cause I'm not in my lap but if it works, you saved my ...

Comment: well, that's what I do, to prevent label from being rendered